# Secure JDBC conection to MySql

Tags: java, mysql

Hello I would like to connect to a MySql server using Secure Password Authentication from a Java program but I am not sure if this is enabled by default and if not how would I enable it given that I am connecting to the server via SSL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Password Authentication is enabled by default as far as I know in MySQL (4.0.4 or later) but you can set the related parameters in JDBC configuration the following way.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database;
Properties info = new Properties();
info.setProperty("user", username);
info.setProperty("password", password);
info.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
info.setProperty("requireSSL", "true");
info.setProperty("serverSslCert", "classpath:server.crt");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
```